# Operation hooks or remote hooks for create method

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a simple question. Whats the main difference doing a `MyModel.beforeRemote('create')` hook for a create method and a `MyModel.observe('before save')`. I already read the docs and I know that operation hooks are not tied to a particular method, but rather are triggered from all methods that execute a particular high-level operation (ex. create). But in this particular example, `MyModel.beforeRemote('create')` will work as same as I do `MyModel.observe('before save')`, right? Or this will execute on other "state" of the api flow?

Remote hook:

```
MyModel.beforeRemote('create', (ctx, next) => {
  console.log("beforeRemote");
  next();
}
```

Operation hook:

```
MyModel.observe('before save', (ctx, next) => {
  console.log("before save");
  next();
}
```

Comment: What language are you using ? Can we see some code ? Please take some time to build a [Complete, Minimal and Verified Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @SuperPeanut as you can see by tags this is related with LoopBack Node.js framework. Thanks, example code added.

Comment: I think you have these reversed. The first code sample is a remote hook and the second is an operation hook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MyModel.beforeRemote('create')` would only be invoked for the 'create' remote method, but `MyModel.observe('before save')` would be invoked for any of these:

- create
- upsert
- findOrCreate
- updateAll
- prototype.save
- prototype.updateAttributes

See the table here for all the remote methods that would invoke each operation hook: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Operation+hooks

Comment: Link is redirecting to the homepage. Any updated link?

Comment: @AzadAnsari https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Operation-hooks.html